# Alignment in cases environment with \hphantom

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, cases, phantom

I am using the `\hphantom` command to center the middle 0, but the middle 0 is still too far left.

Here is a picture of my problem:

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \Delta G = 
    \begin{cases}
            < 0 & \quad A\\
            \hphantom{<}  0 &  \quad B\\
            > 0 & \quad C \\ 
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (quick and dirty)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \Delta G =
    \begin{cases}
            < 0 & \quad A\\
            \hphantom{< \mbox{}}  0 &  \quad B\\
            > 0 & \quad C \\
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need an empty relation symbol with the same width as `>` (or `<`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Delta G =
  \begin{cases}
  < 0 & A\\
  \mathrel{\phantom{<}} 0 & B\\
  > 0 & C
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I wouldn't add `\quad`. Avoid the trailing `\\`; while it has no effect in this particular case, it would have in `align` or similar constructions, producing an empty line. Also avoid `align` for a single equation.

[image]

But why not using `=0`?